# .net assembly does not appear in Excel's References

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop, vba

I'm following Rich Newman's guide to using .net code assemblies in Excel. I have made a small test class called MyPro[p in a project called MyProperty that looks like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class MyProp
    Public Function GetData() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

It compiles fine, puts a CLSID into regedit, and (after browsing to find the TLB) allows itself to be added to Excel's References. However, I can't actually use it. I tried this in VBA:

```
Private Sub test()
Dim test As New MyProperty.MyProp
MsgBox test.GetData()
End Sub
```

Which returns:

"Class does not support Automation or does not support the expected interface"

I *assume* that the error means that it can't find GetData or I'm calling it incorrectly. I have re-added the TLB, with no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the order of operations in the bindings. You can make this work by DIMming the object then Newing it on a separate line.